# Caption of PngBitBtn does not appear when runtime themes are enabled

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

I made simple project with one PngBitBtn and then compiled it with following configuration:

1. runtime themes are disabled

   - Debug mode - OK
   - Release mode - OK
2. runtime themes are enabled

   - Debug mode - OK
   - Release mode - there is no caption on PngBitBtn

The only way to show caption correctly is turn off optimization. Is it possible to solve this problem without turning off optimization?

Thank you in advance, Tim

Tested on Delphi XE3, XE6.
Platform: win32.
PNGComponents version: newest from embarcadero CodeCentral.

print screen:

[image: Print Screen]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you still using PngComponents when Delphi itself now supports PNG images out of the box?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing...

Comment: That's interesting :) I didn't know that Delphi natively supports PNG images. Anyway question is still actual.

Comment: @Tim, out of the box since D2009.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe: So PNGComponents is only for backward compatibility with existing projects and it shouldn't be used at new one?

Comment: @Tim, not necessarily. While TPngSpeedButton, TPngBitBtn and TPngCheckListBox might asd well be replaced with the standard controls shipped with Delphi, TPngImageCollection has still no counterpart. Even TPngImageList has its advantages as it stores the Png images in native PNG format, while the standard TImageList converts to BMP. This might give some significant size differences for DFM files. On the other hand: it is PNG only.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe: Does it mean even if I will use TPngImageList with ColorDepth = cd32Bit, DrawingStyle = dsTransparent and then I'll connect it with standard TButton the conversion PNG -> BMP will be done internally in TButton? To avoid that conversion should I use TPngBitBtn?

Comment: @Tim, a TButton copies the different images as TBitmap into its internal imagelist. A TPngBitBtn doesn't use an imagelist at all. One of the advantages of TPngImageList is that it stores the images in PNG format while a standard TImageList uses BMP format, even if the images are loaded from a PNG file.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe: Ok, all is clear. Thank you for information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply a bug!

To fix it, insert the following line at line 326 in PngBitBtn.pas method TPngBitBtnStyleHook.DrawButton:

```
  Offset := TPoint.Create(0, 0);
```

The code in that area should now look like this:

```
  if not (Control is TPngBitBtn) then
  begin
    inherited;
    Exit;
  end;
  Offset := TPoint.Create(0, 0);
  DrawRect := Control.ClientRect;
```